# Move an entire child directive to a new location

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm creating two Angular directives that serve as a special kind of list. One is the parent, and the others are items in the list. The problem I'm running into is that one of the child items has to be lifted out of the list to be displayed at the top, inside the parent.

But I have no idea how to move a whole directive/$scope to a new location in the DOM. The DropDown collects all the available children, will set one as its main and then makes a list of the rest. But I can only transclude the whole content. (which will not put `<li>` tags around the rest, which ideally it should also do, so I want to control their placement as well)

I've put a short version of what I'm trying to accomplish below; ideally I should be able to control where each of the dd-item directives in rendered within the template of the dropdown. I tried using a template function, but it doesn't seem to have access to its children, nor does it have access to a $scope.

```
<dropdown>
  <dd-item href="#test1">Name</dd-item>
  <dd-item href="#test2">Name2</dd-item>
  <dd-item href="#test3">Name3</dd-item>
</dropdown>

angular.module('x').directive('ddItem', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: '^dropdown',
        scope: {
        },
        transclude: true,
        template: '<a ng-transclude></a>',

        compile: function( $element, $attr) {
            return function ($scope, $element, $attr, dropdown) {                    
                dropdown.addItem($scope);
            }
        }

    }
})


angular.module('x').directive('dropdown', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {},
        transclude: true,
        template: '<div><button>' +
            'the main element should be here...' +
            '</button>' +            
            '<ul><li ng-repeat="item in items"></li></ul>', // this will not work either, as I do not know how to render the whole element here
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attr) {
        },
        controller: function ($scope, $timeout) {

            $scope.main = false;
            var items = $scope.items = [];           

            this.addItem = function (item, title) {
                if (!$scope.main) {
                    $scope.main = item;
                }
                else {
                    items.push(item);
                }
            }
        }

    }
})
```

The expected outcome for this example should be this. But each of the three  elements should still be a dd-item directive, so simply outputting the html isn't a solution. More behaviour will be added to the dd-items at a later time.

```
<div>
  <button>
    <a href="#test1">Name</a>
  </button>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#test2">Name2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#test3">Name3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: hard to understand why you have hard code  repeated  `ddItem` markup but parent `<dropdown>` directive uses `ng-repeat`. WHat is transcluded final expected result?

Comment: I added the expected outcome to the question. The ng-repeat probably won't work either, because I'd need to output the whole directive there as well, but Transclusion won't work because it would output all of the elements as they are; I can't wrap them nor can I remove the one that I moved up.

Comment: `<a>` as child of `<button>`? Doubt that is valid and semantically doesn't make sense either. Why isn't `<ddItem>` in the `dropdown` template instead of hard code inside html? Seems like you need to rethink logic a bit

Comment: The <ddItem> are not always the same, they are loaded and inserted dynamically by the templating system that generates the page's html. I should probably the '<button>' with a '<div>', but it doesn't really change the problem of picking whichever <ddItem> is rendered first (something outside of javascript's control) and moving it to a new location.

Comment: you can always use link function to modify dom elements and combine with template and then call `$compile()` yourself. Sound like you have too many template systems at work

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should try this using a single directive, dropdown - then provide a list of items from your controller scope.

By clicking on an item, you essentially set that item as the "main item" your button is bound to.

Are you sure you're dropdown needs transclude? Because you might want to have more than one dropdown on a single page/controller, and an isolated scope will provide this for you.

Take a look at this plunkr; http://plnkr.co/edit/xK4qdjmE0BErdID2xTIH

```
.directive('dropdown', function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
          items: '=items'
        },
        // transclude: true, // i don't think you need this
        template: '<div><button ng-click="firstItem.func(message)">Main Element: {{firstItem.name}}</button>' +
          '<ul><li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="makeFirst(item)">{{item.name}}</li></ul>',
        link: function($scope, $element, $attr) {},
        controller: function($scope, $timeout) {
          $scope.firstItem = $scope.items[0];
          $scope.message = "hi from dropdown";
          $scope.makeFirst = function(item) {
            $scope.firstItem = item;
          };

          $scope.addItem = function(item, title) {
            items.push(item);
          };
        }
      }

<dropdown data-items="items">
</dropdown>
```

Comment: I was using the Transclusion becuase many of the items in the dropdown include things like icons or have other directives attached to them, which'd also need to be copied over.
This looks like a good fix, but is there any way to have complicated elements also look and work as they do in their original html? (I realise that maybe my example is a bit tóo simplistic; some of the buttons might also contain their own html other than just a title)

Comment: For icons, the path should remain the same with or without transclusion. If you'd like directives within directives this is fine but it's a good idea to isolate scope for your directives, and just pass in the data-params you need for each directive. If you decide to transclude everything, you'll be 'massaging' your controller $scope to ensure each directive on the page has access to it's objects. You can have complicated elements within directives (and you can also hook into dom/jquery objects inside each directive to make it look prettier, more functional)